# PostScript /(font name) FindFont produces "not found, using Courier."

Tags: fonts, postscript

I want to use a windows font  in a .ps file which I will convert to PDF using Distiller

Distiller->settings->Font Locations has C:\Windows\Fonts in the list of places to look

Lydian Regular is a truetype font in c:\Windows\Fonts and its embedability is defined as print/preview

The instruction
/(Lydian Regular) findfont
(in the .ps file I create) generates an error "Lydian Regular not found, using Courier."

So how to I get Distiller to use this (Lydian Regular) font and embed it in the pdf?

TFAI

Comment: I found an old file LYDIANN.TTF listed as LydianBT-Roman by fontforge. If your font is the same then "/LydianBT-Roman findfont" might work if your Distiller knows about the font. TrueType fonts work fine with ghostscript.

Comment: Try this postscript in Distiller to see your fonts: (*) {==} 128 string /Font resourceforall

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix and match names and strings like that. You've correctly realised that you can't have a space in a name, so you can't have:

```
/Lydian Regular findfont
```

You are correct that it needs to be handled as a string `(Lydian Regular)` but you can't just stick a '/' in front, that doesn't make the string into a name. To make the string into a name you need to use the `cvn` operator:

```
(Lydian Regular) cvn findfont
```

However, the 'key' passed to findfont need not actually be a name, it's permissible for it to be any type, if it was previously associated with a font by use of definefont. It is probable that Distiller is seeing your code as the following tokens:

```
/
(Lydian Regular)
findfont
```

So that's an empty name on the stack, then a string, then findfont. Findfont will then look for a font defined with a string. I'm guessing that won't work no matter what.

So I would start by using the cvn operator.

But note that this **still** may not work, because the font may not be called 'Lydian Regular' (in PostScript). Note that the name on disk doesn't necessarily bear any relation to the font name, as defined internally in the font.

Also PostScript cannot use TrueType fonts directly, they have to be formatted as type 42 fonts. A number of PostScript interpreters (eg Ghostscript) can use TrueType fonts from disk as if they were Type42 fonts, but this involves a degree of guesswork. I've no idea if Adobe Distiller can do this or not.

Comment: Sorry but I am still confused. 
/(Calibri) cvn findfont works fine and the output is in Calibri
but 
/(Lydian) cvn findfont does not (font not found)

Both Calibri and Lydian are in W:\Windows\fonts which is on Distillers path to look for fonts

I tried converting Lydian.ttf to Lydian.t42 and putting that on a path Distiller searches but that didnt work (Font not found)
.
https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/font-handling-in-acrobat-distiller.html says Distiller recognises truetype fonts

So please how can I make this work?

Comment: And I've tried fonts whose embedibiltiy is described as 'Editable' and that doesnt work!

Comment: Using "/(fontname) cvn" causes the interpreter to put an empty name object "/" on the stack, then a string object, then convert the string to a name. That then leaves two name objects on the stack, / and /fontname. If you then execute findfont it consumes the top object leaving the empty name object on the stack. As I noted in my answer the most likely problem is that the internal font name is not the same as the filename. Could be Lydian-Regular or Lydian,Regular or just Lydian, for example. I don't have the font so I can't really guess.

Comment: Open the Lydian.t42 file in an editor and look for the /FontName definition. That should tell you how to specify the font in the postscript language. Both the TrueType and the Type42 font should have the same name so which font gets loaded by Distiller might depend on the search order assuming the fonts are installed so Distiller can find them.

Comment: Yup that did it. No idea if distiller used the typ 42 or the truetype as both were in the directory - I'll do a bit more research. Thanks for your help